# Create an array of array values by key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional array in the following format:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
  (
  [title] => First
  [count] => 765
  [description] => Description
  )
[1] => Array
  (
  [title] => Second
  [count] => 90
  [description] => Description
  )
[2] => Array
  (
  [title] => Third
  [count] => 1080
  [description] => Description
  )
)
```

I'm stuck trying to take this array and get all of the 'count' values. That is, turning the above array into:

```
Array (
[0] => 765
[1] => 90
[2] => 1080
)
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: StackOverflow is not code generator.

Comment: I have got as far as this:

`<?php 
 for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
  {
  print_r($count_array[$x][count]);
  }
?>`

Just not sure how to get those values into an array.

Comment: I never asked for code, @PLB, Mr. Alien and Gordon; you've been very rude putting my question 'on hold'. Thanks to another user (Ken Gregory) who pointed me in the right direction I was able to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could write the code for you, but that feels wrong.  Let me point you in the right direction.

Start here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

You can iterate the array using a key-value foreach and use each array item, which is another array, to access the count and create your new array.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks to your direction, I found the answer.